# Optimize spatial intersect PostGIS POLYGON table with large PostGIS POINT table (point-within-polygon test)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a very large table with a PostGIS POINT geometry column, about 1.7 Billion points. I want to query all points that fall within a number of 30 PostGIS polygons, stored in another table. Both geometries are WGS1984 (EPSG:4326).

I expect that this query will take very long (e.g. days) and I am trying to understand a) how to use the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in pgadmin and b) how to optimize this query.

My current query:

```sql
WITH hotspots AS (SELECT geom, hotspot_id FROM spatial.hotspots)
SELECT t1.post_guid,
       t1.origin_id,
       hotspots.hotspot_id,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t1.post_publish_date) AS "year"
FROM topical.post t1, hotspots
WHERE ST_Intersects(post_latlng, geom)
AND t1.post_geoaccuracy IN ('place', 'latlng');
```

I know that my bottleneck is IO and I identified this with `iotop`:

> be/4 systemd-  847.96 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 98.55 % postgres: postgres db 127.0.0.1(33090) WITH hotspots AS

My questions specifically:

- I don't know how to test the "real" query, as it takes very long
- should I perhaps create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` with only a subset of points, e.g. based on Postgis `box2d` intersection, and then run the detailed POLYGON intersection?
- the point table `geom` has a **gist** index:

  ```sql
  CREATE INDEX gix_latlng_geom ON topical.post
  USING gist (post_latlng);
  ```

  Perhaps something else is faster?
- is there some measurement available, as inaccurate as it may be, that I can use to estimate the total running time of the query? Based on the 2000 points of the test-query-db and the 36 ms from ANALYZE, can I exprapolate this to the real 1.7 Billion points table? I get 7.3 days estimate.

pgadmin visualizes my test-data (2000 points) `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (including cost and timing) as this, but it doesn't help me:
[image]

---

**[Edit]**

After noticing that my Server only consumed 1 Gb of total 10GB of memory, I changed two settings:

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET work_mem = '64MB';
ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_buffers = '5000MB';
```

Particularly large size `shared_buffers` [is said](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/optimize-postgresql-server-performance) to work well for read-heavy DBs. After increasing this from 500 to 5000MB, my query finished after just 21 hours. This is no scientific analysis, and I don't have comparison values. Check the comments: A proper approach would likely need to be based on partitioning, e.g. based on UTM zones.

Comment: I have never handled so many rows. But with my data [subdividing](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html) the polygons and then create a new index help alot.

Comment: What makes indexes miracuously fast, _generally speaking_, is their logarithmic traversal - i.e. the index traversal of 2 Billion elements adds _one_ lookup step over an index of 1 Billion elements (≈ 30 vs. 31 operations). _If_ that table is `VACUUM ANALYZE`'d, those polygons of moderate size (i.e. < 500 vertices) and the points not heavily clustered in or around the polygons in question - and your DB cluster is able to hold the GIST imdex in memory - that query should not take more than 10 seconds. With one or more of these conditions not met, times easily increase up to an hour.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful: I think I need to find out why my postgres DB is only using 1.03 GB of available 9.69 GB memory.

Comment: Ok, so this is a testing ground now: I first increased `shared_buffers` from `500MB` to `5000MB`, as it is recommended for 'read-heavy' queries [1](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/optimize-postgresql-server-performance). I have no writes at all, this is a data sink.

Comment: In addition to gist geom indexes on the points and polygons I would experiment with  st_within or st_contains. You also might want to try just the bounding box query 1st ex: a.geom && b.geom

Comment: the bounding box spatial query is built INTO the st_intersects function but I have had success explicitly using it in the where clause before st_intersects/st_within/st_contains

Comment: Your sample size is way too small... 36ms is nothing, won't reveal any bottleneck, and the planner can take a different path than when applied on all/larger dataset.

Comment: That being said, you can try to build a partial spatial index only, so the filtering will be already done.

Comment: Partial index is a brilliant idea! If this solves my problem, I will report a solution in a dedicated answer.. thank you.

Comment: You don't give an indication of the bounding box on the data, or how it was loaded/organized. If I had a global terabyte table, I'd be using a server with at least 256GB RAM, and I'd partition the points table by UTM zone and build a clustered index on ST_Y value to defragment the points and speed the index efficiency. Depending on selectivity, I might subpartition by accuracy.

Comment: Yes, it is a global dataset and my filters for which I need to retrieve data often only apply to small, regional subsets. Unfortunately, 9GB is the maximum number of memory I will get for this server. But partitioning should still help here, thanks!

Comment: By the way: After increasing the `shared_buffer` to 5000MB, the query finished after just `21 hours`! And these were quite complex polygons. It is just stunning what Postgres (14) can do with so little hardware.

Comment: You can also try the SPGIST index https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/the-many-spatial-indexes-of-postgis for more performance.

Comment: _"And these were quite complex polygons."_ --> subdivide! See this [article](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/11/subdivide.html) showing a 60x improvement